# Getting the Notepad F5 Date & Time in Python

Tags: python

In my project, I need to get the date and time. I've researched a lot of ways but they are all a bit too confusing to me. Something I've noticed though is that when you press `F5` in Notepad, it will give a date and time similar to this: `6:30 PM 6/9/2020`. Is there any way i could automate this process of pressing F5 in the Notepad and defining that as a variable? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can type this code:

```
import datetime
time = datetime.datetime.now()
print(time)
```

You can also make it beautiful and more clear like this:

```
time_clear = time.strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")
print(time_clear)
```

Comment: Sorry for adding this comment so long after your answer, but is it possible to get the millisecond? I've looked at the time module docs and cant seem to find anything.